# Vuejs - watch nested object in 'this' not self

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i watch nested object. but data property undefined.

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!',
    item: {
      foo: 'test',
    },
  },
  //for test run, wait 3000ms
  mounted(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      this.item.foo = 'a';
    }.bind(this),3000);
  },
  watch: {
    'item.foo': (newVal, oldVal) => {
      console.log(newVal); // running
      this.message='new Hello'; // but this.message undefined
    },
  },
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LgpzLa

Comment: avoid using `arrow function` in Vue instance, create a function using [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) instead.

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú, oh thanks. I didn't know that. solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using nested watch statements (e.g. `object.parameter`) you should use regular functions instead of lambda;

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!',
    item: {
      foo: 'test',
    },
  },
  //for test run, wait 3000ms
  mounted(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      this.item.foo = 'a';
    }.bind(this),3000);
  },
  watch: {
    'item.foo': function(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log(newVal); // running
      this.message='new Hello'; // but this.message undefined
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular Vue methods:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!',
    item: {
      foo: 'test',
    },
  },
  //for test run, wait 3000ms
  mounted(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      this.item.foo = 'a';
    }.bind(this),3000);
  },
  watch: {
    'item.foo': 'itemFooChanged'
    },
  },
  methods:
  {
    itemFooChanged (newVal, oldVal)
    {
      console.log(newVal); // running
      this.message='new Hello'; // this.message works
    }
  }
});
```