# Access a vue.js "methods" from a custom object property within the same file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a custom property named "meta" with some values. I would like to reference a callback function to one of those methods placed inside the "methods" object.

Is there any methods to make it a part of vue's instance where I can access "data, methods, computed" and so on ?

Here is the part of code:

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Articles',

  meta: {
    topmenu: [
      {
        label: 'Create new',
        handler: () => {
          this.onCreateNew() // <-- unable to call this method
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  methods: {
    onCreateNew () { // <-- unaccessible from meta.topmenu[0].handler
      console.log('creating new item')
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPTION A)**

1. Don't use arrow functions in vue instance
2. Use the bind() *subfunction*

```
    label: 'Create new',
    handler: function() {
        this.onCreateNew();
    }.bind(this);
```

Reference:
[Vuejs - watch nested object in 'this' not self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605458/vuejs-watch-nested-object-in-this-not-self)

**OPTION B) (hacky)**
In javascript you can declare global variables by using the **var** keyword, doesnt matter what the scope is.
So, you can *globalize* the vue instance in mounted() hook like:

```
    ...
    mounted() {
       var self = this;
    },
    methods: {...}
    ...
```

Then use **self** in any other place:

```
    ...
    handler: () => {
      self.onCreateNew() // use "self" instead
    } 
    ...
```

You can also access data, methods, computed, etc. Just like you would with the keyword this, but instead use self.

However, you must do the *var self = this* for each vue component you want this behaviour, and since they are global variables, they should have different names or they might collide and cause unwanted effects.(examples for names are: selfFoo, selfBar, fooSelf, thisArticle,selfArticle,etc)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I went with Option B. Option A with `.bind(this)` didn't helped somehow. I've declared a `let vm = null` between `import` and `export` lines, and then did a `vm = this` in mounted hook, and it worked.